# PostgreSQL 11.5 doing sequential scan for SELECT EXISTS query

Tags: postgresql

I have a multi tenant environment where each tenant (customer) has its own schema to isolate their data.  Not ideal I know, but it was a quick port of a legacy system.

Each tenant has a "reading" table, with a composite index of 4 columns:
site_code char(8), location_no int, sensor_no int, reading_dtm timestamptz.

When a new reading is added, a function is called which first checks if there has already been a reading in the last minute (for the same site_code.location_no.sensor_no):

```
   IF EXISTS (
        SELECT
            FROM reading r
            WHERE r.site_code   = p_site_code
            AND   r.location_no = p_location_no
            AND   r.sensor_no   = p_sensor_no
            AND   r.reading_dtm > p_reading_dtm - INTERVAL '1 minute'
    )
    THEN
        RETURN;
    END IF;
```

Now, bare in mind there are many tenants, all behaving fine except 1.  In 1 of the tenants, the call is taking nearly half a second rather than the usual few milliseconds because it is doing a sequential scan on a table with nearly 2 million rows instead of an index scan.

My random_page_cost is set to 1.5.

I could understand a sequential scan if the query was returning possibly many rows, checking for the existance of any.

I've tried ANALYZE on the table, VACUUM FULL, etc but it makes no difference.

If I put "SET LOCAL enable_seqscan = off" before the query, it works perfectly... but it feels wrong, but it will have to be a temporary solution as this is a live system and it needs to work.

What else can I do to help Postgres make what is clearly the better decision of using the index?

EDIT: If I do a similar query manually (outside of a function) it chooses an index.

Comment: For some reason PostgreSQL is thinking the predicate `r.reading_dtm > p_reading_dtm - INTERVAL '1 minute'` is not selective enough.

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with cached execution plans inside the function

Comment: It could be - if I imitate the query manually it chooses an index scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the engine is evaluating the predicate and considers is not selective enough (thinks too many rows will be returned), so decides to use a table scan instead.

I would do two things:

- Make sure you have the correct index in place:

  ```
   create index ix1 on reading (site_code, location_no, 
                                sensor_no, reading_dtm);
  ```
- Trick the optimizer by making the selectivity *look better*. You can do that by adding the extra [redundant] predicate `and r.reading_dtm < :p_reading_dtm`:

  ```
   select 1
   from reading r
   where r.site_code   = :p_site_code
     and r.location_no = :p_location_no
     and r.sensor_no   = :p_sensor_no
     and r.reading_dtm > :p_reading_dtm - interval '1 minute'
     and r.reading_dtm < :p_reading_dtm
  ```

Comment: Yep, option 2 seems to have fixed it.  I remember doing something like that before now and not being sure why it worked.  That's definitely one to document, as I imagine anyone looking will wonder why..